# Advice: Best way to create investment records, is creating 2 new entities efficient

Tags: civicrm-entity

I want to track financial investments in our companies.
Lets say we have an organization Testco in our database.
I want to be able to track any investments made into Testco and be able to search them and provide reports off of them.
I feel like using a lot of custom fields will not give me the power I need. So far I was thinking of the following schema.

```
Investment Round [Entity]{
    Consists Of 
        Investment[Entity]{ // can contain many records with the same id to reflect investment timeline (considering, committed, closed, and funded)
            Consists Of
                To: Organization
                From: Organization
                Investment Type: Custom Field //grant, convertible note, cash, in-kind services,equity
                Organization Fund: Custom Field
                Investment Status: Custom Field(timestamp auto-update on status change to provide timeline)
                Amount: Custom Field (money)
                Date: Custom Field (status based)

            }
        Date Begun: Custom Field (date)
        Date Ended: Custom Field (date)(auto-update)
        Goal: Custom Field (money)
    }
```

As you can see, this would require creating two new entities. Any advice as to an easier way to achieve this? And if this is in fact the best way to move forward, any tips? I feel like creating a new entity(component) is relatively underdocumented.

My thanks,

Comment: Have you considered creating a custom Activity for the 'investment'?

Comment: Is there good documentation on doing this? I've had litle success in finding it...

Comment: Not sure what you need. This link will add a new Activity Type on demo. http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/options/activity_type?reset=1 You can then make new Custom Fields that are specific to that Activity Type. I don't know how good a match it is for your requirement, but is more 'out of the box'